# Wordpress Plugin imagemapper not working in specific page

Tags: php, wordpress, imagemap

http://webexperts.pt/gyspot/

this is my page , i am using the default theme and editing it , however when I insert my Imagemapper in this specific page -> http://webexperts.pt/gyspot/, it appears like text, it seems like the page don't accept the imagemapper .. but when i try in a different page for example home or about it works perfectly .

[imagemap id="31858"] -> this is what i use to call the imagemapper, the plugin is called imagemapper.

The shop page is calling a WOOCOMMERCE template, and the theme of the site is bridge, i've already tried to call

```
echo do_shortcode( '[imagemap id="31858"]' );
```

is there anyway for me to use the imagemapper in my page

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

this solved my issue i used

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_content',' [imagemap id="31858"] ');
```

instead of do_shortcode